# `cat` analogue for highlighting different matches in different colors

Tags: linux, terminal, grep, syntax-highlighting, log4cxx

My question is similar to this one: [Syntax highlighting/colorizing cat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7851134/syntax-highlighting-colorizing-cat) . But not exactly the same.

A tool, doing this would be great:

- `cat` a file
- highlight word `x` in color `cx`
- highlight word `y` in color `cy`

etc. Does anyone know something like this?

---

The "real-world motivation" for this is: I have a log (generated by `log4cxx` for example) and I want to highlight `DEBUG` in one color; `ERROR` in another; `WARN` in third, etc.

Basically, what I'm trying to achieve is: [How to set colour of console output of log4cxx?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14118703/how-to-set-colour-of-console-output-of-log4cxx#comment24900994_14118703)

I think about some kind of combination between `cat` and `grep` (with custom colors). But an external tool would do the job, too (if exists).

Ideas?

---

**EDIT:**
Thanks, **@sjngm**! Great suggestion. I modified it a bit (now can be used as `alias` and also the whole rows are highlighted). I decided to post my modifications, as this could be useful for somebody:

```
 # escaped ' ------------v;         light red ------vvvv;  red ------------vvvv;  yellow -------vvvvv;  green ---------vvvv;  brown ----------vvvv;  dark gray ------vvvv
 alias log_color='nawk '"'"'BEGIN { arr["FATAL"] = "1;31"; arr["ERROR"] = "0;31"; arr["WARN"] = "1;33"; arr["INFO"] = "0;32"; arr["DEBUG"] = "0;33"; arr["TRACE"] = "1;30"  } { l = $0; for (pattern in arr)     { gsub(".*" pattern ".*", "\033[" arr[pattern] "m&\033[0m", l); } print l; }'"'"
 alias log_error='grep "FATAL\|ERROR\|WARN"'
```

Example usage:

```
$ cat log_file | log_color
$ cat log_file | log_error | log_color
```

Comment: Have you seen [multitail](http://www.vanheusden.com/multitail/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A while ago I did something similar, also for a log-file, with `nawk`:

```sh
cat yourfile | nawk '
BEGIN {
    arr["EXCEPTION"] = "0;31";
    arr["\\[ERROR\\]"] = "1;31";
    arr["\\[WARN\\]"] = "0;31";
    arr["\\[INFO\\]"] = "1;34";
}
{
    l = $0;
    for (pattern in arr) {
        gsub(pattern, "\033[" arr[pattern] "m&\033[0m", l);
    }
    print l;
}'
```

The configuration part should match your `x => cx` style, you could also use `tail -f` instead of `cat`.

To be honest I don't think there's a tool for it as it's not that complex.

Comment: Nice! Sorry for the late reaction, I totally forgot about this question :)

Comment: @KirilKirov No problem, as long as it is useful to you it's fine with me :)

Answer (score 0):

Here you will find a sed-wrapper that will simply accept colors and patterns as a command line arguments:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13593327/1033410

(usage: cat yourfile | colorize.sh red ERROR yellow WARN blue 'user .* logged in')